# Active Directory "refresh" migration

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

We have one domain which is historically being kept alive since Win2003 and it went trough a lot and lost some child domains, which I was not able to get rid off (tried ntdsutil and all I found on the net), also it went trough few restores, some upgrades and the whole Domain controller is a mess now. It is still using FSR, so I can't replicate it to a new server as that is deprecated and migrating to DFS is a no go because of the state of the server it self...

Now I had an idea that I could create a new domain controller and use ADMT to migrate objects to temporary domain, reinstall the original domain and then migrate it back.

Do you think this would be the correct way of handling this or do you have any better suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my god, there is so much in this question. I will try to get over then one by one.

> We have one domain which is historically being kept alive ...

Which is usually no problem at all, a lot of Domains are there since the 2000s. AD is extremely flexible and reliable.

> lost some child domains, which I was not able to get rid off [..]

As the AD is just a LDAP database (and some kerberos, rpc and smb magic) at its core, this *should* be solveable. I can not say more without more input, but in verymost cases the AD is (as long is it is still booting and working somehow) fixable.

> also it went trough few restores, some upgrades [..]

More like the domain is a mess. The DCs are just (multimaster-) holders of replicas of that state. In some cases the operating system under that is a mess, but the AD database itself is proven to be extremely stable and error tolerant.

If the OS is 'done', just replicate it to a new one.

> It is still using FSR,

I interpret this as `FRS` (File Replication Service), which is indeed depricated. But that does not mean FRS isn't working anymore.

> so I can't replicate it to a new server

Why not? Just set up a new one, if you like to. Just don't use Windows Server 2019 (as it does no longer support FRS).

> as that is deprecated and migrating to DFS is a no go because of the state of the server it self...

A migration to DFS usually crashes, if the FRS is done, too. Or if your DNS design is somehow unclean. You will have to fix that beforehand - you'd have do that anyway.

> Now I had an idea that I could create a new domain controller and use ADMT to migrate 
>   objects to temporary domain, reinstall the original domain and then migrate it back.

This makes (technically) sense, if you create a new *domain*, not just a new DC. ADMT will allow you to migrate object with most object properties from one domain to another. You will lose your SIDs, Profiles, SPNs, SCNs, Services and Scheme data, though.

> Do you think this would be the correct way of handling this

I personally would:

- Install a new DC (in case of the old one has some OS related ... stuff) using Server 2008R2/2012R2
- Replicate the domain (and fix all the errors while doing this)
- Migrate cleanly to DFS
- Get rid of older child remains
- Use this clean and working system to migrate to whatever you want to.

Bonus: You can do this while the System is online and working, as there will be no user impact. You can even try to transfer your FSMO roles one by one and test the new systems very intense while everythin ist still up and running.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your input, you are right I have tried to install S2019 to do the replica, so I will install 2012R2.

I have followed various guides how to remove the long time lost child domains, but as far as I remember, ntdsutil ended up saying it cannot remove file leaf ref or whatsoever and the latest attempt over ADSI edit ends up with error 0x2015 when trying to remove the domain record from configuration -> partition section.

Will try to replicate and will see then what to do next.

Comment: Yes, perfect. Get a clean machine and come up with the exact question, like "Error xyz while trying to ...".

Comment: Hello bjoster, here is some more... This particular AD server I have was a replica initially as the PDC was lost. So I managed to claim FSMO roles and I have this old replica with claimed roles + 1 new one installed yesterday. Now I can see on the new one in the event viewer that it is still trying to replicate with all other domain controllers (within the same domain) which are already gone. Will be removing them from "Domain Controllers" OU in Active Directory Users and Computers sufficient for now, or is it supposed to be cleaned more deeply?

Comment: Will try to follow - [This link](https://www.dtonias.com/forced-removal-domain-controller)

Comment: Ok, so my current issue when I try to get rid of lost child domain via NTDSUTIL is that I select the domain i want to remove and then when I issue the command "remove selected domain" I get - DsRemoveDsDomainW error 0x2015(The directory service can perform the requested operation only on a leaf object.)

Comment: I would suggest two things: First check if the to-be-removed child has nested, sub- or linked childs and remove the bottom child first (I have seen this in about 90% of 0x2015) and if not, make a new SF-Question.

Comment: I managed to get rid of the child domain finally... Turns out you need to remove the "delete nc DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=name,DC=extension" 1st and then "delete nc dc=domain,dc=name,dc=extension", now I will proceed with the DFS migration :-)

Comment: Migrated to DFSR without issue :-) I think that I am in state where I wanted to be, thank you very much for your help :-)